# Number of palindromic 6 letter sequences from 4 characters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, palindrome

The genetic code can be viewed as a sequence of four letters T, A, G, and C.
There were two parts to the question:

(a) How many 6-letter sequences are there? I just said $\binom{4}{1}^6$, or $\binom{4}{1}$ choices for each letter.

b is where I am having trouble.

(b) How many 6-letter sequences are palindromic, (read the same forward as backward)? I originally thought that: because for each of the first three letters you get a designated letter for the last three letters, that is if the first is A, the last is A, if the second is T, the second to last is T, etc... So we only need to concern how many options there are for the first three letters. So I thought there should be  $$\binom{4}{1}^3\text{combinations.}$$
Then I thought that we might be over counting though. I can't really explain why I think that. I just wanted to check. What do you think?

Comment: Your solution is great.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'm not sure why you're writing "4 choose 1" (sorry, I don't know the $\TeX$ for that) instead of just "4".

Comment: @StefanSmith He could write that, but it's more clear in terms of combinatorics, where such results are usually expressed in ${n choose k}$ form - otherwise, it might be unclear as to how he got 4.

Comment: @Newb : Thanks.  Even if one knows nothing about combinatorics, if one has to choose one letter out of 4 letters, obviously there are 4 choices.  Maybe this problem is one of a set of more difficult problems, in which case using the "choose" notation would seem to make more sense.

Comment: @StefanSmith: That is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. Is there a way to say mark my question as the answer, then?

Comment: Part (b) can be proven by showing that there is a one-to-one mappping f from  the strings of length 3 to the palindroms of length 6. Define f(xyz)=xyzzyx. So f maps each string of length 3 to a palindrom of length 6.
If a string is a palindrom of length 6 then the string is of the form as xyzzyx (x, y, z from 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G'). We have f(xyz)=xyzzyx, so f is sujective. If f(xyz)=f(abc) then xyzzyx=abccba and so a=x, b=y, c=z and therefore xyz=abc. So f is injective. Therefoer f is a one-to-one mapping and the number of strings of length 3 is euqual to the number of palindroms of length 6.

Answer (score 1):

Both (a) and (b) are correct. In part (a) you have $4$ choices for each letter. Since we are concerned with a $6$-letter sequence we have $4^6$ sequences by the Multiplication Principle. In part (b) we can view our $6$-letter palindromic sequence as a $3$-letter sequence since the last three letters are determined by the choice of the first $3$-letter sequence. So we have $4^3$ $6$-letter palindromic sequences by the Multiplication Principle.

Answer (score 0):

a) is correct.

b) is correct as well. Your reasoning is fine. Note that the number of palindromic 6-letter sequences is the same as the number of unique 3-letter sequences. The last 3 are just defined by the first three.